# Marking folders and getting their Path

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to give user an interface so that he can mark folders and at the back-end I will get their path. But I don't have any idea how to do this. Currenty I am starting an intent to choose image from gallery then save its path. Here is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an Image"),1);
```

But I want instead of image chooser it should display all the folders and user sould mark those, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below links for the file/folder picker Api.

- [Android file dialog.](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/)
- [Open Intent File manager.](http://openintents.org/en/filemanager)
- [Android File/Folder picker](https://github.com/vaal12/AndroidFileBrowser)

Simply just use this API and in onActivityResult, you will get the selected folder/file path.

If you want to implement custom picker then have a look at [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html), this will give you some hint about start.